# Batch script kill process

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, while-loop

I have Process1,Process2,Process3 in tasklist       I want to write for loop or loop back to repeat the same task  to kill the ‘n' number process
Which I mention in batch script.
Below is sample script using to kill process

```
@Echo Off

Tasklist | Findstr /I “Process1”
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :Killprocess
GOTO:EOF

:Killprocess
Taskkill /IM “Process1”
```

Comment: And what is your specific question? Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: You have provided your own tags which means that you've already determined that a `for-loop` may be important here. What happens when you read the information under `FOR /?` and try to implement what you learned from it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to kill the same program over and over, just do tasklist in a cmd.exe, then find its PID tag.
Example:

```
 Image Name                     PID Session Name        Mem Usage
 ========================= ======== ================ ============
 firefox.exe                  26356 Console             139,352 K
 regedit.exe                  24244 Console               9,768 K
 cmd.exe                      18664 Console               2,380 K
 conhost.exe                   2528 Console               7,852 K
 notepad.exe                  17364 Console               7,892 K
 notepad.exe                  24696 Console              22,028 K
 notepad.exe                  25304 Console               5,852 K
 explorer.exe                  2864 Console              72,232 K
```

After that, just put the PID into your text. I would run the program as such:

```
@echo off

TASKLIST
TASKKILL /PID (your PID here) /F
TASKKILL /PID (PID 2) /F
```

This will kill your tasks automatically. You don't need to find the tasks. If the program isn't running, then it won't kill it.

If you have a process that keeps changing its PID, or doesn't run under the same session, then run it as such:

```
@echo off
TASKLIST
TASKKILL /IM (program name) /F
TASKKILL /IM (program name 2) /F
```

Again, the program won't close if it isn't running.

Hope this helps!

[Find more info here...](http://tweaks.com/windows/39559/kill-processes-from-command-prompt/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for suggestions....done with script

```
   @echo off
 set len=3
 set obj[0]=chrome.exe
 set obj[1]=vlc.exe
 set obj[2]=MicrosoftEdge.exe

  set i=0
    :loop
    if %i% equ %len% goto :eof

          for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2"            %%j in (`set obj[%i%]`) do (
          TASKLIST |FINDSTR /I "%%j"
           IF ERRORLEVEL 0 TASKKILL /IM "%%j" /F)


         set /a i=%i%+1
         goto loop
```